# Regex to get a word in a pattern

Tags: java

I don't know how best to word this. I have a set of patterns:
Usa-Texas
Usa-Chicago
USa-Washinton
.
.
Usa-{some USA state}

Now, I need a regex(java) to extract only the USA. I am just wondering why this didn't work :   `"(//busa//b)"` It wasn't extracting the USA..

Comment: Can you paste the actual Java code you are using in your attempts?

Comment: @user200188 you can use this("\\b(?:USA|FRANCE)\\b"), don't forget  If you want you may accept my answer. Good luck

Comment: @Abdelhak, certainly, I will accept your answer. They all work. I just want to know what the ?: in the regex means?
Thanks

Comment: The question mark indicates zero or one occurrences of the preceding element. For example, colou?r matches both "color" and "colour".in your case you can delete the?:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to fix the problem.

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bthis\\b");
 Matcher m = p.matcher("Print this");
  m.find();
 System.out.println(m.group());
```

Output:

```
this
```

Comment: what if the this is not a space separated word like in your example? what if it is something like this : "print-this"

Comment: that print usually this,i tested this solution

Comment: @Abbelhak, what if I want to use the Or so USA or France?
Would this work: "(//busa//b)||(//france//b)" ?